# Strange behavior with bg command

Tags: linux, debian, process

How to send process (application) to background if it always expects input on terminal and sending received data from uart to stdout all the time?

I cannot send my app to background with CTRL+Z & bg %number / bg %%.

Any idea, what is wrong?

My device (program) expects some input commands from terminal for configuration, before it is sent to background. And I'm getting error when try to send it to background.

```
# [CTRL-Z]
[1]+  Stopped                 sudo ./my_app

# bg %1
```

and it display me something like this:

```
[1]+  Stopped                 sudo ./my_app
```

Comment: What happens when you try? Doesn't Ctrl+Z send it to the background? What's the problem?

Comment: App stops, and after command bg %1 , it doesnt continue with execution in background.

Comment: What happens if you just run `bg` alone with no `% 1`?

Comment: it wont work, it just displays my jobs name [number] and that is stopped.

Comment: Huh? `bg` and `bg %1` are equivalent, that's odd. In any case, if your program expects input from the terminal, how can it continue in the background? Please [edit] your question and add more detail, it's hard to understand what you mean.

Comment: @terdon look now

Comment: You need to explain exactly what's going on. Ideally, copy/paste the terminal output so we can see. You mention an error, _what error_?

Comment: Try `jobs` command and look what commands are background. If you have multiply background jobs, just make `fg` {№} of background task.

Comment: Are you sure your application doesn’t attempt to read from stdin?

Comment: It attempts all the time, but what to do then? @IncnisMrsi

Comment: An application issuing a (potentially blocking) read(0,  … ), from unredirected stdin, is stopped when in background. That’s a part of what is known as the *job control*.

Comment: If it needs input all the time, it can't run in the background. Have you checked whether the command has an option to allow it to run in the background? For instance, `ssh` has the `-n` option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a program running in the background attempts to read from the terminal, it is [stopped by a SIGTTIN signal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Job_control_(Unix)#Implementation). The input is currently going to the foreground process¹; it would be disruptive if input randomly went to the foreground program or the background program. So the background program is suspended until it's put in the foreground.

If you only need to pass data to your program at the beginning, pipe the data into it.

```
echo "config=foo" | ./my_app &
```

If you need to interact with the program now and then, but it can go on executing unattended most of the time, run it in a terminal multiplexer such as [Screen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Screen) or [Tmux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmux). For example, with screen:

```
screen -S my_app ./my_app
```

Type the necessary input, then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to detach the screen session, i.e. let it run in the background and go back to the original terminal. When you want to interact with the program again, reattach to the screen session:

```
screen -S my_app -rd
```

If you need to perform some complex interactions automatically, write an [expect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect) script (or a script in another language with a similar library).

¹  <sub>Process group but I'm not going to go into that subtlety here.</sub>

Comment: So tell me, what happens to the foreground process if he doesn't find its controling terminal? @Gilles

Comment: @Junior If the controlling terminal goes away, the process receives a SIGHUP (conditions apply). Of course if it tries to read or write to a nonexistent terminal the operation will fail.

Answer (score 1):

If your command continues to read from the tty, then you need to call

`fg`

after you get a "stopped" message in order to type that expected input.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you pass the arguments to stdin, for it continue to work? If you just CTRL-Z it, it will wait for the input in the background.

e.g.

```
$ cat test.sh
#!/bin/bash

read var
echo $var

$ cat <<EOF > input
d
EOF

$ ./test.sh < input
d

$ ./test.sh <input > stdout 2> stderr &
[2] 23180
[2]-  Done                    ./test.sh < input > stdout 2> stderr

$ cat stdout
d
```

When trying to start it without passing the input:

```
$ ./test.sh > stdout 2> stderr &
[2] 13012

[2]+  Stopped                 ./test.sh > stdout 2> stderr
```

Comment: I just need to send those commands once, at system startup, not all the time.

Comment: Just have the file containing the input in the same place. At boot time, it should still be there and your program will read it as if it were a human manually inputting the arguments. I'm not sure I understand your particular case.